# How to parse pipe-separated Attribute=Values pairs?

Tags: java, indexing, substring, keyvaluepair

I have string `b="Name=Paul Roberts|Telephone=|Address=|City=LA";`
I  have been trying all day to get the output Attribute-Value pairs without equal and pipes signs. I have more then 4 results but this is what I want to achieve:
Output (separate each pair because I have to put  those two values into the fields of some table):

```
Name
Paul Roberts 

Telephone

Address

City
LA
```

So you can notice that VALUE can be null(empty).

I tried with SUBSTRING (maybe there is better way) but getting wrong results:

```
static String b="Name=Paul Roberts|Telephone=|Address=|City=LA";   

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("b="+b);
    String match = "=";

    int i =0;
    while((i=(b.indexOf(match,i)+1))>0)
    { 
    String c=b.substring(0,i-1);
    String d=b.substring(i);
    String match2="|";
    int k=b.indexOf(match2);
    System.out.println("Attribute="+c);

    int j=d.indexOf(match2);
    if (j>-1)
    {
   String e=d.substring(0,j);
   System.out.println("Value="+e);
    }
    if (k>-1)
    {
    b=b.substring(k+1,b.length());
    }
    }
}
```

I am close to the correct result but this is what I am getting:

```
b=Name=Paul Roberts|Telephone=|Address=|City=LA
Attribute=Name
Value=Paul Roberts
Attribute=Telephone
Value=
Attribute=Address=|City
```

So you can notice that last row is not correct and I am missing two rows.
Also is this with SUBSTRING most efficient way?

Comment: +1 for a clearly defined goal, an effort on your part and a description of how close you are to it.

Comment: Although it would help if you'd indent your code more readably. If you're using an IDE, you should find there's an option to do that for you.

Comment: You should also consider using `String.split`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting the string makes this easier:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String b="Name=Paul Roberts|Telephone=|Address=|City=LA";

  for (String s : b.split("\\|")) {
    String[] pair = s.split("=");

    String attribute = pair[0];
    String value = ((pair.length > 1) ? pair[1] : "");

    System.out.println("Attribute=" + attribute);
    System.out.println("Value=" + value);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Attribute=Name
Value=Paul Roberts

Attribute=Telephone
Value=

Attribute=Address
Value=

Attribute=City
Value=LA
```

Comment: thank you very much Duncan for your efforts and kindness.  you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Very basic way to do this would be

```
    String b="Name=Paul Roberts|Telephone=|Address=|City=LA"; 
    b = b.replace("\"", "");
    b = b.replace("|", "\n");
    b = b.replace("=", "\n");
    System.out.println(b);
```

output is

```
Name
Paul Roberts
Telephone

Address

City
LA
```

Again it would be even better if you used `StringBuffer` for it rather than directly operating on Strings.

Comment: Thank you for help but this is not what I want... I must get result in two separate String fields because both Attribute and Value I must insert in one row in two fields of additional table

Comment: Then now you can easily split using `\n` and use it the way you want.